# How do I make a raycast end slightly before hitting an object in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a block-building system, and sometimes the blocks get offset or even clip inside each other when I place them. I'm using a ray-cast to a place where I look, and I'd like to make the ray-cast end slightly before hitting a block to prevent blocks from merging and becoming offset. The blocks I build with are also coded to be snapped to a grid.

Raycast block placement code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            //Make Whatever a Raycast layer or if you don't want it just exclude it
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Whatever.value))
            {
                Point = hit.point;
                Instantiate(stoneBricks, Point, UnityEngine.Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
```

Block grid-snap code:

```
Vector3 b = new Vector3(Mathf.Floor(a.x + 0.0f), Mathf.Floor(a.y + 0.0f), Mathf.Floor(a.z - 0.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`Physics.ComputePenetartion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html)

> Compute the minimal translation required to separate the given colliders apart at specified poses.

So you could do something like e.g.

```c#
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Whatever.value))
{
    Point = hit.point;

    // store your new bricks reference
    var newBrick = Instantiate(stoneBricks, Point, UnityEngine.Quaternion.identity);

    // Now check if there is an overlap
    if(Physics.ComputePenetartion(newBrick.GetComponent<Collider>(), newBrick.transfom.position, newBrick.transform.rotation, hit.collider, hit.transform.position, hit.transform.rotation, out var direction, out var distance))
    {
        // If so move the new brick just far enough away so there is no overlapping anymore
        newBrick.position += direction * distance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try increasing the offset, or try maybe increasing the collider's dimension a bit (Very tiny tiny bit).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.